# How to get data for two columns using right join with MYSQL case

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I want to get the categories pricing, Say if there is data in **customer_category_pricing** table then fetch that pricing for that specific customer. Otherwise fetch default prices from categories table.

i have tried achieving this desired result using mysql case it is working fine, but the problem is, it is returning two rows

- hourly_amount_final column returns updated price then per_day_amount_final returns default price
- Then in next row, hourly_amount_final column return default price and then per_day_amount_final returns updated price.

table: pr_categories

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | title            | hourly_amount | per_day_amount | created_at| updated_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Power Generation | 100.00        | 200.00         | 
| 2  | Local Government | 300.00        | 400.00         |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

table: pr_customer_categories_pricing

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | customer_id | category_id | billing_type_id | amount | created_at | updated_at
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |      1      |      1      |         1       |   109  |
| 2  |      1      |      1      |         2       |   600  |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

table: pr_billing_types

```
----------------
| id | title   |
--------------
| 1  | Hourly  |
| 2  | Per Day |
----------------
```

This is the query i am working with at the moment:

```
SELECT c.id,c.title,
CASE
    WHEN (c.hourly_amount <> (SELECT ccp.amount WHERE ccp.billing_type_id = 1)) 
    THEN (SELECT ccp.amount WHERE ccp.billing_type_id = 1)
    ELSE c.hourly_amount
END
AS hourly_amount_final,

CASE
    WHEN (c.per_day_amount <> (SELECT ccp.amount WHERE ccp.billing_type_id = 2)) 
    THEN  (SELECT ccp.amount WHERE ccp.billing_type_id = 2)
    ELSE c.per_day_amount
END
AS per_day_amount_final

FROM pr_customer_category_pricing AS ccp
RIGHT JOIN pr_categories AS c
ON c.id = ccp.category_id AND ccp.customer_id = 1
```

Expected result **when there is no data** in **pr_customer_category_pricing**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | title            | hourly_amount_final | per_day_amount_final |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Power Generation |      100.00         |      200.00          | 
| 2  | Local Government |      300.00         |      600.00          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected result **when there is data** in **pr_customer_category_pricing**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | title            | hourly_amount_final | per_day_amount_final |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Power Generation |      109.00         |      600.00          | 
| 2  | Local Government |      300.00         |      400.00          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Actual result what i'm getting:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | title            | hourly_amount_final | per_day_amount_final |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Power Generation |      109.00         |      200.00          | 
| 1  | Power Generation |      100.00         |      600.00          |
| 2  | Local Government |      300.00         |      400.00          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What am i doing wrong? Any suggestions! Help a brother out. :S

Comment: Will there be more than one record in pr_customer_category_pricing for each billing type?

Comment: yeah there will be maximum 2 (if the price gets updated for that customer) as there are only 2 billing types for now. @Nick

Comment: OK, but only 1 record for each billing type?

Comment: Absolutely one. yeah. @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there can only be one entry in the `pr_customer_category_pricing` table per billing type, you can simplify things by creating a derived pivot table from the `pr_customer_category_pricing` with values for each of the `billing_type_id` in separate columns. You can then simply `COALESCE` the value from the derived table with the value from the `pr_categories` for each `billing_type_id`:

```
SELECT c.id,c.title,
       COALESCE(ccp.hourly_amount, c.hourly_amount) AS hourly_amount_final,
       COALESCE(ccp.per_day_amount, c.per_day_amount) AS per_day_amount_final
FROM (SELECT
          customer_id,
          category_id,
          MAX(CASE WHEN billing_type_id = 1 THEN amount END) AS hourly_amount,
          MAX(CASE WHEN billing_type_id = 2 THEN amount END) AS per_day_amount
     FROM pr_customer_category_pricing
     GROUP BY customer_id, category_id) AS ccp
RIGHT JOIN pr_categories AS c
ON c.id = ccp.category_id AND ccp.customer_id = 1
```

Output:

```
id  title               hourly_amount_final per_day_amount_final
1   Power Generation    109                 600
2   Local Government    300                 400
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sPBaSDB6ZdVLtw4mLUTDpb/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max()` aggregation with group by

```
SELECT c.id,c.title,
max(CASE
    WHEN (c.hourly_amount <> (SELECT ccp.amount WHERE ccp.billing_type_id = 1)) 
    THEN (SELECT ccp.amount WHERE ccp.billing_type_id = 1)
    ELSE c.hourly_amount
END)
AS hourly_amount_final,

max(CASE
    WHEN (c.per_day_amount <> (SELECT ccp.amount WHERE ccp.billing_type_id = 2)) 
    THEN  (SELECT ccp.amount WHERE ccp.billing_type_id = 2)
    ELSE c.per_day_amount
END)
AS per_day_amount_final

FROM pr_customer_category_pricing AS ccp
RIGHT JOIN pr_categories AS c
ON c.id = ccp.category_id AND ccp.customer_id = 1
group by c.id,c.title
```

Comment: It worked really fine when the amount is greater in __pr_customer_category_pricing__ than the default amount which is in __pr_categories__ but, lets say the updated price is lower than the default price of that category, max wont work in that situation. Sorry i didn't mentioned that earlier. @fa06